# Basic assembly query

Tags: ida, assembly, intel

I wrote a program which will add two numbers in assembly.
When I do a system call for `scanf()`, the instruction looks like this:

```
mov rcx, num1
```

Note: I have defined `num1` in the `bss` section as:

```
num1 resb 10
```

And, when I try to move this value to say `rax` the instruction looks like:

```
mov rax, [num1]
```

From what I have learned, anything inside square brackets must only be computed in case of `rm32`. So, more like going to memory location but not reading what's in the memory.

How is this bracket helping here ?

Why do we need the memory location when we can have the direct value?

And my next instruction is:

```
sub rax, '00'
```

`rax` contains an address of `num1`. Shouldn't we be doing math to the value `num1` and not on the address ?

Comment: just because it's about assembler does not mean it's RE

Comment: Agreed. But it's related.  That's the reason I posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using the Intel syntax for the x86/amd64 assembly. So, in this syntax the brackets (`[.]`) stands for a dereference of the address it contains.

If you know C programming, `[var]` (in assembly) is exactly similar to '*var'.

In fact, the only small difficulty you have to handle here is that the `num1` that you defined is already an address (I am speaking now about the nasm syntax and NOT about the Intel asm syntax).

So, `move rcx, num1` means that you copy the address of `num1` to `rcx`.

And, `move rax, [num1]` means that you copy the content of `num1` to `rax`.

You may refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145243/x86-asm-linux-using-the-bss-section) which might explain your problem.